# Javascript this object inside intervals/timeouts

Tags: javascript, this, setinterval

I have a method that is a big setInterval statement, and it needs access to the *this* object of the object that owns the method from inside the interval. I implemented a simple closure, but it doesn't seem very elegant:

```
connect: function(to, rate, callback){
    var cthis = this,                             //set cthis to this,
    connectIntervalID = setInterval(function(){
        if(cthis.attemptConnect(to)){             //reference it here,
            clearInterval(connectIntervalID)
            cthis.startListening(10)              //here,
            callback && callback.apply(cthis, []) //and here
        }
    }, rate)
}
```

You could also do it with *apply* or *call*, if you wanted to use *this* instead of *cthis*

```
connect: function(to, rate, callback){
    var cthis = this,
    tempFunc = function(){
        if(this.attemptConnect(to)){                 
            clearInterval(connectIntervalID)
            this.startListening(10)              
            callback && callback.apply(this, []) 
         }
     }�       
     connectIntervalID = setInterval(function(){tempFunc.apply(cthis, [])}, rate)
 }
```

However, that seems even worse...

Comment: That's JavaScript, for better or worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `.bind` makes it a bit better (in my opinion, you may or may not agree):

support code:

```
function $A(args){
   var out = [];
   for(var i=0, l=args.length; i<l; i++){ out.push(args[i]); }
   return out;
}

Function.prototype.bind = function() {
   var __method = this, args = $A(arguments), object = args.shift();

   return function() {
      return __method.apply(object || this, args.concat( $A(arguments) ));
   };
};
```

and your code becomes:

```
connect: function(to, rate, callback){
    connectIntervalID = setInterval((function(){
        if(this.attemptConnect(to)){             //reference it here,
            clearInterval(connectIntervalID)
            this.startListening(10)              //here,
            callback && callback.apply(this, []) //and here
        }
    }).bind(this), rate)
}
```

But I'm afraid you won't get a whole lot better.

Comment: MDC notes that the real ES5 bind method does deviate in behavior - you will want to test in both ES5 and non-ES5 browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is more-or-less the standard way to do this.  My only suggestion would be to call your variable something other than cthis; make it descriptive of the object being bound.

Javascript 1.8.5 adds Function.prototype.bind to solve this problem in a different way, but that's not a useful solution for most people.

Comment: Why is `bind` not a useful solution for most people? It's trivial to do feature detection and add it when it doesn't exist.

Comment: @theazureshadow it's useful, but only if you need it repeatedly. For one-off uses, the feature-detection and support code is not worth it.

Comment: @Box9: I see where you're coming from, but I think many people would find the readability gain to be worth it for normal use (especially if they use it in multiple projects whenever the need comes up). It's a useful tool in the toolbox because it describes the closure rather than leaving it implicit (not to mention potentially accidental).

Comment: it's 1.8.5, only in the newest firefoxes, I develop in chrome 12, which has 1.6 or 1.7, but otherwise it would work

Answer (score 0):

I'd break out the `setInterval` function into its own function, attached to the same object as `connect`. In this way, it will be clear that `this` refers to the same object:

```
connect: function (to, rate, callback) {
    var obj = this;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        obj.connectInterval(intervalId, callback);
    }, rate);
},
connectInterval: function (intervalId, callback) {
    if (this.attemptConnect(to)) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        this.startListening(10);
        callback && callback.apply(this, []);
    }
}
```